# How do I create an elegant accordination menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I'm trying to create an expanding and collapsing menu to work on a **mobile device** such as iOS, so that as you click on each item, it expands the containing menu (if it exists).

If you click on the item again, it will close the relevant enclosed menu.

However I'd also like to create an accordination animation, so that if you click on another item while there are other nested menus open (*within the current part of the menu tree*) it will close all other open menu's and open the the new menu.

I've managed to create a crude implementation of this using various tutorials, but I'm struggling to create it in a **really elegant** way that works properly. I've seen the JS that some people write for this kind of thing and I can never understand it.

Please see my attempt in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W59P9/5/

It ***kind of*** works, but it's pretty buggy and sometimes causes double animation and or doesn't work at all. It's especially buggy when you have gone down the tree a few times and then try to close items within that tree or from the top of the tree.

Comment: [why](http://moofx.mad4milk.net/) [not](http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/accordion/index.html) [use](http://www.solutoire.com/experiments/mootools/acc_ex3.html) [a](http://www.chrisesler.com/mootools/mootools-accordion.html) [ready](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxAccordion/index.shtml)[-](http://www.scriptocean.com/accordion.html)[made](http://www.p51labs.com/accordion/) [solution](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)?

Comment: [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html)?

Comment: Thanks. Can you recommend any other plug ins? Hopefully I'll be able to find a home-spun solution as it would be fantastic to learn from and keep as lean as possible.

Comment: Sorry Eliran, only just realised your answer contains many examples.

Comment: sure, no problem. go out and play :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js">        </script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({ active: false,
        collapsible: true
    });
});
</script>
<div id="accordion">
<h3>
    <a href="#" style="background-color: Blue; height: 25px; color: White; text-decoration: none;">
        Start Service</a></h3>
<div style="height: 40px;">
    <span>Start or Stop Servcice </span>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
        <p>
            some text
        </p>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
<h3>
    <a href="#" style="background-color: Blue; height: 25px; color: White; text-decoration: none;">
        Customer Service</a></h3>
<div>
    <b>Contact Us</b>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlSrvc" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
        <p>some text<p>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
<h3>
    <a href="#" style="background-color: Blue; height: 25px; color: White; text-decoration: none;">
       some text</a></h3>
<div style="height: 40px;">
    <span>some text </span>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
        <p>
            some text
        </p>
    </asp:Panel>


</div>
<h3>
    some text
</h3>
```

This is something that I am using on my mobile site and its working good..It has some of my project code but I hope u'll fig out what you want ...

Comment: Thanks Scorpio, I take it that I don't need the `<asp:/>` tags?